# kendoNumericTextBox number and Decimal Format in Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendonumerictextbox

I have Requirement like this.i should show format like 9999.000 in kendoNumericTextBox with in the grid how to do it ..

**note** :After decimal point It should accept Only 3 zeros(3 decimal Points)

Answer (score 0):

you can specify format in column specification :

```
{ field: "fieldName",type:"number", format: "{0:n3}" }
```

Comment: its not working @Vijay i think it should be like **format: "#.000" **

Comment: are you using template or editor? If editor, you can specify decimal property in kendoNumeric Control.

Comment: iam working with editor .  your solution will work in other format. thank you

Comment: in editor speicfy:

kendoNumericTextBox({
...
decimal:3,
...
})

Comment: already i did it but it takes only 2 decimals even i declare  decimals: 3

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem like this:

```
.kendoNumericTextBox({
    placeholder: "select value",
    format: "#.000"
});
```